# List of highest rated entries in Solspace Rating

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

I got this problem: My entries are rated (star-rating, just submits a value between 1 and 5). Now I want to show on a single-entry-pages the top-rated entries of the category the actual entry is in.
Example:
We are on entry-page "Snoopy" which is filed in the category "dogs". I want a list like
"Best rated entries in dogs:
- Snoopy xxxxx
- Other dogs xxx
- My dog xx
- My mother's dog xx

I tried for hours and hours, but with no success. Perhaps anybody could give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

I got a lot of code snippets that all don't work, here is one:

```
<ul class="">
{exp:rating:rank channel="{my_channel}" limit="3" category = "2" dynamic="no"} 
 {exp:rating:stats}             
  <li>
   {title} - {overall_avg}
  </li>
 {/exp:rating:stats}
{/exp:rating:rank}
```

This one just shows me nothing. If I remove the exp-rating-stats-loop it only shows me 3 times the actual entry.
I would appreciate any help very much - thanks!

EDIT: FURTHER EXAMPLES

Here are some examples: In an empty template this generates the correct output, 5 entries with their titles:

```
{exp:rating:rank category="24" limit="5"}
{title}
{/exp:rating:rank}
```

while in my standard-template there is no output. When I add the parameter dynamic="no" I get the entry of the page I am.

EDIT 2: EXP:CHANNEL:ENTRIES-LOOP

When I put it OUTSIDE the exp:channel:entries-loop, it works. My loop is

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{snp_my_channel}" limit="1"
disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination" track_views="two"
status="open" cache="no" refresh="2500"
require_entry="yes"}
```

But I need it inside the loop. Is there perhaps any parameter missing?

Comment: What version of Rating are you using? Also, why is there a `{exp:rating:stats}` tag pair inside `{exp:rating:rank}`? Have you tried just using `{exp:rating:rank}` and see if the `{title}` is displaying at least?

Comment: I am using 3.2.3. Added some examples in my original post, perhaps you could have a look?

Comment: So `{exp:rating:rank}` is within `{exp:channel:entries}`? Any reason for that? Since both tags share the same Channel Entries library and have many variables and tags in common, you will run into variable clashes. Use `{exp:rating:rank}` *outside* of `{exp:channel:entries}`, or use an embed for `{exp:rating:rank}`.

Comment: Hey @Solspace, moving it to a template did the trick. Perhaps you should mention explicitly in the docs that exp:rating:rank has to be outside the exp:channel:entries-tag. Please write an answer with this so I can marked this as solved. Thanks for your fast and competent support!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `{exp:rating:rank}` was inside a `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair.

Since both tags share the same Channel Entries library and have many variables and tags in common, you will run into **variable clashes**. In other words, EE will be confused about which variables to parse for which tag pair, etc. Use `{exp:rating:rank}` outside of `{exp:channel:entries}`, or use an embed for `{exp:rating:rank}`. In other words, use:

```
{exp:channel:entries /* your other parameters */}
  // Some entry data
  {embed="rating/rank"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

or even better:

```
{exp:channel:entries /* your other parameters */}
  // Some entry data
{/exp:channel:entries}

<h3>Top entries</h3>
{exp:rating:rank /* your other parameters */}
  // Some ranked entry data
{/exp:rating:rank}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it miss the entry id:

```
{exp:rating:stats entry_id="{entry_id}"}
```

Or could be a parsing problem:
try to insert: parse="inward"

```
{exp:rating:rank channel="{my_channel}" limit="3" category = "2" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Stephane. I don't think the entry_id is needed, because I don't want to show the reviews for one entry, but just a list of rated entries. Use of the parse-parameter changed nothing.

Comment: do you use Low Variables or Stash?? Perhaps could be a parsing order......

Comment: none of them ...